# SQLite operators not working with single digit numbers

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, select, where-clause

I have a basic SQlite table set up to log MQTT messages. Payload carries a range of inputs (int, float, string) depending on message topic.

```
CREATE TABLE mosquitto(
    TIMESTAMP INT NOT NULL, 
    DATE TEXT NOT NULL, 
    PAYLOAD TEXT NOT NULL, 
    TOPIC TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

IF I try to search the database for values, for example

```
SELECT * FROM mosquitto WHERE topic = 'Temperature' AND payload <= 2;
```

it doesn't work.

If I create a double digit number by adding say 10, it does

```
SELECT * FROM mosquitto WHERE topic = 'Temperature' AND payload +10 <= 12;
```

Is this becuase text is sorted alphabetically like in JavaScript?

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

Your column is of `TEXT` datatype, so comparisons follow different rules than when dealing with numbers. For example, string-wise, `'10'` is smaller than `'2'`, because the former starts with `'1'`, and the latter with `'2`'.

When adding a number to a string, SQLite implicitly converts the text to a number - which is actually what you intend.

You could just add `0`, so you don't need to change the value on the right side:

```
SELECT * FROM mosquitto WHERE topic = 'Temperature' AND payload + 0 <= 2;
```

Or you can explictly `cast()` the text to a number, which might make the intent somehow clearer:

```
SELECT * FROM mosquitto WHERE topic = 'Temperature' AND cast(payload as int) <= 2;
```

A definitive solution would be to fix your data model, so each different payload attribute is stored in a different column, with the proper datatype - depending on your use case, this might, or might not, be feasible.

Comment: Correct, I will check it.